# Using .append to iterate upon an expanding list of numbers in Python

Tags: python, list, append, iteration

Both these methods return a None type; their purpose is to append a new number equal to 1 higher than the final integer in the list. The dual print statements are just to test the viability of the code in a loop. What am I doing wrong so as to not get the desired result?

**Method 1:**

```
number_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
number_list = number_list.append(number_list[-1]+1)
print(number_list)
print(number_list)
```

**Method 2:**

```
number_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
number_list = number_list.append(number_list[0]+number_list[-1])
print(number_list)
print(number_list)
```

Comment: list.append(x) updates the list and does not return anything. Don't save it's return value and just print number_list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you dont need to numberlist = numberlist.append(...)

just

```
numberlist.append(..)
```

Comment: When I test this, both the print statements return the same list rather than building upon each other. Is that just solved by the use of a for loop, or is there another issue keeping the .append from repeating?

Comment: cause both your print statements are after the fact, place one before the append and you will see that it adds a new element to the list

Answer (score 0):

`.append` returns `none` which is what you are setting `number_list` to. Instead, use the method without setting it to `number_list` and it will work fine.

```py
>>> number_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
>>> number_list
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> number_list.append(number_list[-1]+1)
>>> number_list
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

> You might have noticed that methods like insert, remove or sort that only modify the list have no return value printed – they return the default None. 1 This is a design principle for all mutable data structures in Python. [[source](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)]